# PHP : Gmail authentication in my application - will oAuth do this better?

Tags: php, oauth, openid

In my project all the Gmail users can access my application. So I referred Google API, The suggest me to use OpenID / OAuth.

1. Could you say which one is better.
2. I referred many no. of tutorials regarding oAuth, but none of them satisfied me.
3. So Please advice, the simple method to achieve this.

Comment: this answer/question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76184/php-tutorial-for-openid-and-oauth/159089#159089

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [OpenID+OAuth Hybrid](http://googlecodesamples.com/hybrid/) protocol as it lets you combine an OpenID request with an OAuth authentication request. This extension is useful you if require the use both OpenID and OAuth, particularly in that it simplifies the process for users by requesting their approval once instead of twice.

It means you can use google APIs aswell as pull back the user's information. [This is a very interesting article](http://softwareas.com/oauth-openid-youre-barking-up-the-wrong-tree-if-you-think-theyre-the-same-thing) on the differences and similarities of oAuth + openID.

However, if you don't need to use any of the google API's and just need to pull back user info have a look at [LightOpenID](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid) - it is really easy to use. and has an out-the-box example with Google OpenID

Comment: But just I need to identify the user is having the account in Gmail ?

Comment: nice LightOpenID is trully a nice openid consumer :)